# Why is AMD Pro GPU slower than generic Intel GPU on hybrid laptop?

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

My laptop is HP ZBook 14u G5 (https://support.hp.com/rs-en/document/c05873311), with two GPU:

- Intel UHD Graphics 630
- AMD Radeon Pro WX 3100

On Ubuntu 19.04, I'm able to see both graphic cards:

```
$ inxi -G

Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 driver: i915 v: kernel
           Device-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Lexa XT [Radeon PRO WX 3100] driver: amdgpu v: kernel
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.4 driver: amdgpu resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2) v: 4.5 Mesa 19.0.2
```

And I'm able to select which GPU to use for a given application using the `DRI_PRIME` environment variable:

```
$ DRI_PRIME=0 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)
$  DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon Pro WX3100 (POLARIS12, DRM 3.27.0, 5.0.0-19-generic, LLVM 8.0.0)
```

What bugs me is that the integrated GPU (Intel) seems to perform better than the discrete GPU (AMD Pro), whereas I expected the Pro GPU would be largely better. I have observed that in Steam games (I passed the `DRI_PRIME` variable to select the GPU when launching the games), but also when launching benchmarks:

- with Intel integrated GPU:

```
$ DRI_PRIME=0 glmark2
=======================================================
    glmark2 2014.03+git20150611.fa71af2d
=======================================================
    OpenGL Information
    GL_VENDOR:     Intel Open Source Technology Center
    GL_RENDERER:   Mesa DRI Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)
    GL_VERSION:    3.0 Mesa 19.0.2
=======================================================
[build] use-vbo=false: FPS: 2670 FrameTime: 0.375 ms
[build] use-vbo=true: FPS: 2997 FrameTime: 0.334 ms
[texture] texture-filter=nearest: FPS: 2753 FrameTime: 0.363 ms
[texture] texture-filter=linear: FPS: 2806 FrameTime: 0.356 ms
[texture] texture-filter=mipmap: FPS: 2413 FrameTime: 0.414 ms
...Ctrl+C
=======================================================
                                  glmark2 Score: 2727
=======================================================
```

- with AMD Pro discrete GPU:

```
$ DRI_PRIME=1 glmark2
=======================================================
    glmark2 2014.03+git20150611.fa71af2d
=======================================================
    OpenGL Information
    GL_VENDOR:     X.Org
    GL_RENDERER:   AMD Radeon Pro WX3100 (POLARIS12, DRM 3.27.0, 5.0.0-19-generic, LLVM 8.0.0)
    GL_VERSION:    4.5 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 19.0.2
=======================================================
[build] use-vbo=false: FPS: 501 FrameTime: 1.996 ms
[build] use-vbo=true: FPS: 591 FrameTime: 1.692 ms
[texture] texture-filter=nearest: FPS: 538 FrameTime: 1.859 ms
[texture] texture-filter=linear: FPS: 589 FrameTime: 1.698 ms
[texture] texture-filter=mipmap: FPS: 598 FrameTime: 1.672 ms
...Ctrl+C
=======================================================
                                  glmark2 Score: 563
=======================================================
```

Is it normal? Is there a way to investigate more? Is there any hope to get better performance in Ubuntu with the AMD Pro GPU?

Thanks in advance to all.

Comment: I have the same issue on Windows after some of the recent updates although it worked very good earlier, so may be not hardware related.

Comment: Every 6 months I upgrade to the newest Ubuntu release and I launch the benchmark.No luck so far, the numbers are still the same: the dedicated GPU is largely slower than the integrated one.

Comment: I reset all the settings in my AMD control panel on Windows and this made a huge difference. So yes, it is clearly software related. And it may be possibly not solved anytime soon, as our graphics cards are quite rare in terms of overall laptop market.

Comment: Oh sure, I imagine this is a software issue, and you're right, there will surely never have a solution for Linux/Ubuntu. So bad...